# MikTeX Package Manager keeps the download status as 'downloading' even after the package had finished downloading and installing

Tags: miktex, installing

For example while installing the 'cancel' package the package had finished downloading and installing but the download dialogbox keeps showing the status as downloading as shown below in my Windows 8.1. This happens for any package I install via MikTeX package manager:

[image]